# Spring Data Elasticsearch support for @Embedded

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Does Spring Data Elasticsearch support @Embedded annotation on the entity? Can someone point me to an example?

Version: spring-data-elasticsearch 2.1.4.RELEASE

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: No type specified for field [address]
```

And code would be...

```
@Embedded
private Address address = new Address();
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Embedded` annotation comes from `javax.persistence.*` package and is used for mapping with underlying relational model. If you need to store related entity in the same elasticsearch document, add additional annotation for elasticsearch, depending on your needs:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
```

or

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
```